# Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME)) When Try to CreateVideo from a PowerPoint press object

Tags: c#, video, com, ms-office, powerpoint

I am having a problem when trying to CreateVideo from a PowerPoint using the NetOffice.
My code is

```
var app = new Application();
app.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;

var press = app.Presentations.Open(data.LocalFileName);

//This is the error break: 
press.CreateVideo(data.VideoLocalFileName);
```

I am getting Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))  in the inner exception.

I tried:

1. Run as administrator
2. Change the office.dll & Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.dll versions and tried to work without the NetOffice.
3. Created the video file before convert.
4. I Changed the video formats.

Nothing worked until now.
I use 32 bit PC (tried 64 as well), VS2015, Framework 4.5, Office 2007

Please help me.

Regards
H

Comment: I suspect Office 2007 is your problem.  The ability to export videos was introduced in PowerPoint 2010, so there wouldn't be any CreateVideo method in 2007.

Comment: Yup, using the wrong version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint doesn't help you discover this.  Upgrading the Office version is the only real fix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem.